# webAudio - webRTC echoCancellation constraint doesn't seem to work

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api

I am hearing my own voice come back from remote client during a webRTC call. What comes out of the speaker is picked up by the mic. I have applied `echoCancellation:true` and also tried it for `false` but there seems to be no effect at all.

After failing to make it work, I want to try custom echoCancellation using webAudio. I tried to find some code example on the internet but I failed. Can anyone help with an echo cancellation implementation using webAudio?

Thank you

Comment: can you provide some code? We could fix why the echoCancellation doesnt work, instead of re-making the wheel...

Comment: @divinelemon I have searched on SO and the internet in general, it seems mobile(android) browsers don't cancel echo. With headphones it works fine.

Comment: Oh, I wasn’t aware of that.